# Import export widget in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Is there any way how to import/export a widget configuration from one page (or project) to another?

I was thinking of exporting the widget config to a JSON and then importing this config to the other "empty" widget of the same type.

Another way would be to save a widget as global (Elementor approach).

This is something many creators must have confronted: Is there a workflow for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is not widget content export/import or cut/paste across pages in Apostrophe 2. Only within a page via duplicate or drag/drop. If it's a widget type that is frequently reused across pages (such as an advertisement block) it works well to create a piece type for the content. Then use a `joinByOne` field in a widget to connect the content for reuse.

In Apostrophe 3 this is a core feature, however. We did away with drag/drop in favor of cut/paste. This works across pages/tabs as well as within a page.

[image]